Birkat haGomel: 'tov' vs. 'tuv'
I have always wondered why birkat hagomel and the traditional response use the word ‘tov’ three times when the word ‘tuv’ seems more correct/appropriate. Occasionally (quite rarely), I hear people recite it with ‘tuv.’ While I am aware of the Talmudic origin of this blessing (Berakhot 54b), I am not aware of the origin of the specific language. What is the origin of the language 'tov?'

Why does "tuv" seem more appropriate to you? Please [edit] to clarify

Doesn't "tuv" mean "best of"?

Hi David and welcome to MY! Have you considered accepting my answer?

There is a debate both here and regarding the Grace After Meals, whether the word טוֹב itself is both a noun and an adjective or only an adjective. Seligman Baer comments on the matter in his siddur Avodat Yisrael (p. 559):

ויש לדעת, כי נקוד התבה בשורק בסדורי הספרדים, וכן נקד גם אבודרהם ובעל אור חדש דף ל"ג וכן בסדור ר"ע. אבל בעל ש"ת נקד וכל טוב ומכל טוב שניהם בחולם, וכן גם רוו"ה בסדורו, והוא הנכון, כי הלשון הוא יגמלנו לעד חן וחסד וכו', וכל טוב הוא כלשון גמלתהו טוב (משלי ל"א, י"ב), והלשון ומכל טוב אל יחסרנו הוא כלשון לא יחסרו כל טוב (תהלים ל"ד, י"א), ובשניהם טוב בחולם.‏
It should be known that the vocalisation of the syllable is shuruq in the prayer books of the Sephardi Jews, and so vocalised it Abudarham and the author of Or Chadash p. 33, and it is so in the prayer book of R' Emden. But the author of Shaarei Tefillah vocalised both וכל טוב and מכל טוב with cholam, and so did R' Heidenheim in his prayer book, and that is the correct, because the wording is יגמלנו לעד חן וחסד etc., and all טוב is like the phrase גְּמָלַתְהוּ טוֹב (Proverbs 31:12), and the wording ומכל טוב אל יחסרנו  is like the phrase לֹא יַחְסְרוּ כָל טוֹב (Psalms 34:11), and in both of them טוב is with cholam.

So in short, his reasoning is that due to similar verses in Scripture it should be rather with cholam [o] instead of shuruq [u], but most contemporary editions avoid such alterations to bring the orthography of Mishnaic Hebrew closer to Biblical Hebrew.

I'd appreciate if you could point me to an edition of Or Chadash.

Many contemporary editions are actually inconsistent here ושלום וכל טוֹב ומכל טוּב לעולם

@DoubleAA Look at R' Emden. It's interesting why he uses both forms in עמודי שמים. In לוח ארש ס' תל"ה he writes that both versions are correct and Hanau is stretching the words of Radak.
